# how to pass subquery als list into map

Tags: apex, soql, list, map

I have a soql with a subquery. What is the easiest way to pass the id of the query and the list of the subquery into a map.

Do I need to create a loop for the subquery and ad them first to the list?

Tried

```
 Map<id,List<edition__c>> bookMap = new Map<id,List<edition__c>>(); 
List<book__c> bookList = [select id, (select id,name from editions__r) from book__c];
for(book__c ti : bookList){
    bookMap.add(ti.id,ti.editions__r);  
}
system.debug('bookMap: ' + bookMap);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be `bookMap.put` instead of `bookMap.add` in your code. I don't see any other problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my 2 cents here, you could do it in a more elegant way:

```
Map<id, book__c> bookMap = new Map<id, book__c>(
    [select id, (select id, name from editions__r) from book__c]
); 

//now you have access to the children from the parent record and it's mapped to parent id
for(book__c book : bookMap.values()){
    System.debug(book.editions__r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map keys are unique. So, if he adds multiple items with the same key, it will cause a problem. Try this code

```
List<Account> temp = new List<Account>([SELECT id,name from account]); 

Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

for(Account acc:temp)
    accountIds.add(acc.Id);

List<opportunity> oppList= [select name,AccountId from opportunity where AccountId IN :accountIds];

Map<Id,List<Opportunity>> oppMap= new Map<Id,List<Opportunity>>();



for(Opportunity opp:oppList){  

    if(oppMap.containsKey(opp.AccountId)){
       List<opportunity> opp2= oppMap.get(opp.AccountId);
        opp2.add(opp);

        oppMap.put(opp.AccountId,opp2);

            }else{

            List<opportunity> opp1=     new List<opportunity>();
                opp1.add(opp);

                oppMap.put(opp.AccountId,opp1);

            }     

}


for(Id accId:oppMap.keySet()){

    system.debug('Account Id'+accId);

    system.debug('List of opportunities'+oppMap.get(accId));


}
```

Comment: I guess this would be you answer for another question?

Comment: I just gave an example where an parent record can contain multiple child records in a format you wanted.

Map<Id, List<childObjectRecords>>